# SQL query on artists, albums and songs

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem...

In MS Access I have a form where you can search on Artists, Albums and Songs. Now I want to query the search result, but I am not sure if it is possible. Here is an example of my database:
[image]

Now I want to search for artists, albums and songs. When it finds an artist, I want the album and number column to be empty. When it founds an album, I want to fill the artist and album column and the number row must be empty. When it founds a song, I want all 3 columns filled

Is this anyhow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id as artist_id, name as artist_name,
       null as album_id, null as album_name,
       null as track_id, null as track_name
from artists
where . . .    -- your conditions here
union all
select null as artist_id, null as artist_name,
       id as album_id, name as album_name,
       null as track_id, null as track_name
from albums
where . . .    -- your conditions here
union all
select null as artist_id, null as artist_name,
       null as album_id, null as album_name,
       id as track_id, name as track_name
from tracks
where . . .    -- your conditions here
```